# pm2 memory usage and number of processes keeps going up

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, memory-management, pm2

I'm running a node's project on a server with `8G of RAM` and `8 Core of CPU` running `Ubuntu OS`.
I've created `4 instances` of my project but what I'm seeing now is lots of processes using lots of RAM (about 7.5G out of 8G).

How can I manage and remove extra processes keep memory usage in a proper value?

PM2 Version: `4.4.1` 
Ubuntu Version: `18.04`
NodeJS Version: `10.22.0`

here you can see `htop` result:
[image: htop result]

Comment: What do you see from `pm2 monit` ?

Comment: @O.Jones There is only 4 instances of my app without any log in the right hand side.